# Finding details of ancestor's trial at Chester Assizes in 1847

Tags: 1840s, court-records, cheshire

Are there any web-sites with English criminal records from 19th century available?

Comment: It's almost easier to ask which search-sites *don't* have collections of English criminal records.  For example, Ancestry has the collection [England & Wales, Criminal Registers, 1791-1892](https://www.ancestry.com/search/collections/1590/) which may include the records you are looking for.

Comment: Would the county council (Chester) have any addditional records in analog form ie papers which they dont put on-line?

Comment: Well you can search the catalogue for Cheshire Archives [here](http://catalogue.cheshirearchives.org.uk/CalmView/default.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any case papers do survive, then they should be at the National Archives in the ASSI series.

https://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/help-with-your-research/research-guides/criminal-trials-assize-courts-1559-1971/